# Can you specify allowSubDirConfig in the web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

Is it possible to set the allowSubDirConfig to False in the web.config of the actual virtualdirectory?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Have you tried it? This one seems like a few minutes to experiment can go a long way towards the answer.

Comment: i tried it and it did not work, hence asking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to set it in the web.config, this is a property in the Virtual Directory level that has to be specified inside ApplicationHost.config. It is only exposed in IIS Manager inside Configuration Editor since it is an advanced setting that is not commonly required.